# Set SQL date boundaries for a rolling month cycle using today and the day of billing

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a billing day where a person is billed on the 9th of every month, and another is billed on the 25th of every month.

Suppose it is the 14th currently. How do you construct the boundaries of the billing cycle using SQL, taking into consideration today's date?

We only have this information:

- billing date (e.g., `9`, `25`)
- current date (`2022-06-14`, which we can also break down into `14` if needed)

We want to get

- For the user billed on the 9th, we want `2021-06-09` - `2021-07-09`
- For the user billed on the 25th, we want `2021-05-25` - `2021-06-25`

Database: Snowflake (ANSI)

Comment: Date/Time manipulation is heavily dependent on the specific database. Which database are you using?

Comment: Snowflake, I've updated the question

Comment: Since you're on snowflake you might try to use TIME_SLICE() with 1 MONTH to get the month ranges, and then conditionally subtract a month if DAY(CURRENT_DATE()) < billing_date.  Then DATE_ADD those with either your 9 or 25 days.

Answer (score 1):

I think the below code should solve your problem:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST.BILLING_DATES 
AS 
SELECT 1 AS ID, 9 AS BILLING_DAY
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS ID, 25 AS BILLING_DAY;

SELECT 
    ID,
    BILLING_DAY,
    CASE 
        WHEN DAY(CURRENT_DATE) <= BILLING_DAY
        THEN ADD_MONTHS(DATE_FROM_PARTS(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), MONTH(CURRENT_DATE), BILLING_DAY), -1) 
        ELSE DATE_FROM_PARTS(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), MONTH(CURRENT_DATE), BILLING_DAY)
    END AS LOWER_BOUND_DATE,
        CASE 
        WHEN DAY(CURRENT_DATE) <= BILLING_DAY
        THEN DATE_FROM_PARTS(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), MONTH(CURRENT_DATE), BILLING_DAY)
        ELSE ADD_MONTHS(DATE_FROM_PARTS(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), MONTH(CURRENT_DATE), BILLING_DAY), 1)
    END AS UPPER_BOUND_DATE
 FROM TEST.BILLING_DATES;
```

The CASE WHEN statement checks whether the billing day is before or after the day of the current date and based on that the lower and upper boundary of the billing_period is set.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry had to decline because this actually doesn't adhere to calendar months

Comment: `date_from_parts(2022,02,30)` returns 2022-03-02

Comment: Hi brienna, could you give me more context what would happen when the billing day is on a 29th, 30th or 31st of a month? How should e.g. the February be handled if the billing date is the 31st?